# how to logout from the trigger command line toolkit

Tags: trigger.io

How do I log out from the commandline toolkit?

I first used the commandline toolkit when I was testing trigger.io. I used an private mail account to log in in the command line toolkit. Now I have setup a trigger.io account on my company's mail account. In the web toolkit I can switch between the accounts without a problem, but the toolkit seems to be stuck in the first account.

I keep getting errors like these:

```
$HOME/Library/Trigger\ Toolkit/forge --username *** --password **** build ios
[   INFO] Forge tools running at version 3.3.83
[   INFO] Update result: you already have the latest tools
[  ERROR] Forge API call to app/1e44d7acaa4711e4bca212313b0234c0/should_fetch_core_instructions went wrong: Unknown error
```

If I run the create command I only see the projectId from my trial email account.

```
$HOME/Library/Trigger\ Toolkit/forge --username **** --password **** create -v
[   INFO] Forge tools running at version 3.3.83
[  DEBUG] Checking for update zip...
[  DEBUG] Forge build tools version: 3.3.83
[  DEBUG] main: {"server": "https://trigger.io/api/"}
[  DEBUG] port: 38394
[  DEBUG] GET https://trigger.io/api/v1/version_check/3/3/83/
[  DEBUG] Checking API response for success or error
[   INFO] Update result: you already have the latest tools
[  DEBUG] GET https://trigger.io/api/v1/auth/loggedin
[  DEBUG] Checking API response for success or error
[  DEBUG] already authenticated via cookie - continuing
[  DEBUG] GET https://trigger.io/api/v1/project
[  DEBUG] Checking API response for success or error

Choose the project ID for your app:
XXXX    TestTrigger

Project ID:
```

it looks like it completely ignores the username/password arguments and logs me in because I am already authenticated by cookie

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and asked the support of Trigger.io. It took only a few minutes for them to respond and the solution is pretty simple:

> Logout of your own account. You can either do this via the Toolkit or
>   by deleting the following file:
>
> `<trigger toolkit location>/build-tools/cookies.txt`

On OSX this file is located at:

`$HOME/Library/Trigger\ Toolkit/build-tools/cookies.txt`